# confluent schema registry doesn't validate schema for json data

Tags: java, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to send json data to topic which is attached to schema registry. However, when I am sending data it's accepting everything.

**client.properties**

```
bootstrap.servers=pkc-xxx.northamerica-northeast1.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='xxx' password='Y0LiwuvfvDts/iQEXntX/yyy';
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
key.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
#value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

value.serializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer
confluent.value.schema.validation=true
latest.compatibility.strict=false
auto.register.schemas=false
use.latest.version=true


# Required connection configs for Confluent Cloud Schema Registry
schema.registry.url=https://xxx.us-east1.gcp.confluent.cloud
basic.auth.credentials.source=USER_INFO
basic.auth.user.info=xxx:YrE7Oztqrx7FvGKF6Ofk+yyy+YySi
```

**Topic Schema**

```json
{
  "$id": "http://example.com/myURI.schema.json",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "description": "Sample schema to help you get started.",
  "properties": {
    "age": {
      "description": "The string type is used for strings of text.",
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "age"
  ],
  "title": "SampleRecord",
  "type": "object"
}
```

```java
  @Test
    public void testMapUser() throws IOException {
        String topic = "gcp.test_user_schema";
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        InputStream inputStream = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("src/main/resources/client.properties"));
        props.load(inputStream);
        Producer<String, Map> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        File initialFile = new File("src/test/resources/user.json");
        InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(initialFile.toPath());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        HashMap event = gson.fromJson(reader, HashMap.class);


        ProducerRecord<String, Map> kafkaRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, event);

        // Send the record to Kafka topic
        producer.send(kafkaRecord);
        producer.send(kafkaRecord, (metadata, exception) -> {
            if (exception != null) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Message sent successfully!");
                System.out.println("Partition: " + metadata.partition());
                System.out.println("Offset: " + metadata.offset());
            }
        });

        producer.flush();
    }
```

**user.json**

```json
{
  "age": 30,
  "name": "gaurang"
}
```

**Topic Details**

[image]

**Update**: Use JsonNode object as suggest in comment but still the same issue. topic accepts all the messages.

```java
   @Test
    public void TestJsonNodeObject() throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        String topic = "gcp.test_user_schema";
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        InputStream inputStream = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("src/main/resources/client.properties"));
        props.load(inputStream);
        Producer<String, JsonNode> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
        
        File initialFile = new File("src/test/resources/user.json");
        InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(initialFile.toPath());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(reader);
        ProducerRecord<String, JsonNode> kafkaRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, jsonNode);

        // Send the record to Kafka topic
        producer.send(kafkaRecord).get();
        producer.flush();
    }
```

Comment: Kafka includes Jackson, by the way. You don't need to use Gson

Comment: so I have to use a searlizer to convert my json into java object first and then send it to kafka. however, if I am doing so, jackson parser would validate the schema even before I send message, so what's the use of having schema registry ?

Comment: I never said you needed a POJO. A Map can work, but the values of that map cannot be a String **and number**... All I said was that you don't need to use a separate JSON library for serialization. There are plenty of blogs how/why Schema Registry is used such as [this one](https://www.confluent.io/blog/schema-registry-kafka-stream-processing-yes-virginia-you-really-need-one/). Plus, `confluent.*.schema.validation` property on Confluent Server will prevent bad data from being sent into the topic, whereas Kafka will blindly accept any serialized payloads, even non-JSON for example.

Comment: So if map values can’t be numbers or strong then what it should be

Comment: Think about Java objects, not JSON. You've defined just `Map`, not `Map<String,?>` the value of a map can only be one type, no more... If you want different types, create a JsonNode object rather than a Map, or do create a POJO with typed fields... As mentioned before, there's a jsonschema2pojo plugin to create such a class for you automatically

Comment: the issue is not creating a pojo object, it's just if I am creating pojo object, my validation is happening as part of converting json to object. they why would I need schema registry.  The only purpose I wanted to use schema registry is to validate json file aginst schema.

Comment: The validation happens in the Kafka serializer when an HTTP request is made to the registry, not when the Gson library is parsing the file. In fact, your code never references any locally stored schema definition here. Therefore, that's the "use of having schema registry"

Comment: updated the question, even with `JsonNode` object. it behaves same. it accepts everything, even though message has wrong type for age and additional field.

Comment: The Confluent Server/Cloud server-side validation logic is closed source, so I cannot help further. I suggest you contact Confluent Support to see if they can diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

setting following properties, did the trick.

```
props.put(KafkaJsonSchemaSerializerConfig.FAIL_INVALID_SCHEMA, "true");
```